# SpringCloud Config Server: Path Mapping Conflict with SwaggerUI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, swagger-ui, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am running a SpringBoot config server (with Vault backend) and tried to add Springfox SwaggerUI to it. But since I do not want a prefix (`spring.cloud.config.server.prefix`) for my config server, the path mapping between the config server and SwaggerUI results in a conflict.

All my clients ask the config server with the following pattern:

```
{config-server-host}/{application-name}/{profile}
```

For example:

```
{config-server-host}/test-app-one/dev
{config-server-host}/test-app-two/prod
```

But my SwaggerUI path maps to:

```
{config-server-host}/swagger-ui.html
```

As a consequence, the config server complains that the app "swagger-ui" cannot be found or that no profile was specified.

This is the configuration of my `Docket` bean for the SwaggerUI:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .paths(not(regex("/error.*")))
                .paths(any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        Contact contact = new Contact({secret}, {secret}, {secret});
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title({secret})
                                   .description({secret})
                                   .version({secret})
                                   .contact({secret})
                                   .build();
    }
}
```

This all results in the following question: I cannot have a prefix for the config server and I want the SwaggerUI url mapped to the standard. Is there any possibility to tell the config server that it should exclude the `/swagger*` paths?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? What url pattern do you want your config server to work with when you try to fetch a specific profile's properties ? Fundamentally, if you have the Docket bean configured correctly for Swagger then it would always work fine with the standard url <<host>>/swagger-ui.html.

Comment: @Hary as described, I want my config server to work without a prefix. The profile should therefore be accessible by the clients using the following pattern: `https://{config-server-host}/{application-name}/{profile}`. This works fine so far. My `Docket` bean is also being created, but when I open `https://{config-server-host}/swagger-ui.html` the SwaggerUI page is loaded (header bar + logo appear) but no endpoints are shown. And the log tells me that no application or profile was found (since the overlapping paths create a conflict).

Comment: @Hary this is the log message: `Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentNotFoundException: Profile Not found`. And a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/h7seNyw.png) of the empty SwaggerUI. And another [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BMOIxzM.png) of the mapping of my endpoints. I guess that I if I removed the pattern `https://{config-server-host}/{application-name}-{profile}` from the url pattern, it might work?!

Comment: Please share your Docket bean configuration

Comment: Also, what endpoints have you exposed in your config server that you want to see the documentation for in Swagger?

Comment: Thanks for your support already @Hary, I added the `Docket` bean config above. For testing purposes, I added a `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix` to my app config and then the SwaggerUI works, because when adding the `prefix`, the paths don't overlap anymore: `https://{config-server-host}/{prefix}/{application-name}/{profile}` VS. `https://{config-server-host}/swagger-ui.html`. But I don't want/need this prefix. As seen in this [screenshot](https://image.ibb.co/kupVO0/sagger-as-it-should-work.png), I simply want to list my generated config server endpoints within SwaggerUI.

Answer (score 1):

The `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix` parameter in the `bootstrap.properties` file fixed the issue for me.